# Type is inferred as any with find moongose typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have the following content in my `models/areas.ts` file:

```js
import { Document, model, Schema } from 'mongoose'
import uniqueValidator from 'mongoose-unique-validator'

interface IAreas extends Document {
  abstract: string,
  code    : number,
  image   : string,
  name    : string
}

const Areas = new Schema(
  {
    abstract: {
      required: true,
      type    : String
    },
    code: {
      default: 1,
      type   : Number
    },
    image: {
      default: '',
      type   : String
    },
    name: {
      required: true,
      type    : String,
      unique  : true
    }
  }
)

Areas.plugin(uniqueValidator)

const AreasModel = model<IAreas>('areas', Areas)

export { AreasModel, IAreas }
```

And the following in my `controller/areas.ts` file:

```js
import { AreasModel, IAreas } from '../models/areas'

const getAll = async (): Promise<IAreas[]> => {
  try {
    const areas = await AreasModel.find({}, '-__v')

    return areas
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('There was a problem trying to get all the areas.')
    throw error
  }
}
```

So, the problem I have is that the `areas` variable is being inferred as any, I don't know why, I have others projects where it is being inferred correctly.

[image: Evidence]

Here I the versions I'm using:

```
typescript: ^4.1.3
ts-node: ^9.1.1
mongoose: ^5.11.12
@types/mongoose: ^5.10.3
```

Comment: Does your getAll has an unseeded `await` or should it not return a promise?

Comment: It was a code misspelling. I've corrected it. Your were referring to the `await` without the async, right?

Comment: Hm.. not sure I understand enough JS, I would remove the async and the Promise type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what solved my problem was to delete the `@types/mongoose` and the `@types/mongoose-unique-validator` packages.